# difficulty with search url in django

Tags: python, django, search

I am relatively new to Django and while trying to implement a search feature in my site, I am having difficulty with setting the URL in urls.py. My search url dispatcher looks like the following:

url(r'search/$','welcome.views.search',name='search'),

Also my search form has action set to 'search'.

There seems to be no problem with the search functionality but the every time i repeat search, the url looks pretty bad. For example:

http://localhost:8000/search/search/search/search/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=1ZiSKyYHDogluHWoKSHKxo2DdHD8wotp&q=a

The above is the url obtained after trying four successive searches.Please help me out friends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are giving relative path instead of absolute -

So use, `href="/search/*` instead of `href="search/*`.(replace the star obviously with any extra paramaters)

Also use caret in your regex(that would be a stricter regex)

```
url(r'^search/$','welcome.views.search',name='search'),
```

instead of

```
url(r'search/$','welcome.views.search',name='search'),
```

Answer (score 2):

your href might be wrong, try this:

```
href="/search/?params=lala"
```

instead of

```
href="search/?params=lalala"
```

also you forgot the caret which matches the start of the string.